# Problem about Eigen Values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n\times{n}$ matrix over $\mathbb C$ such that every non zero vector of $\mathbb C^n$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Which of the following are true?

1. All eigenvalues of $A$ are equal.
2. All eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct.
3. $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda$, where $I$ is $n\times{n}$ identity matrix.
4. if $\chi_A$ and $m_A$ denote the characteristic and minimal polynomial respectively then $\chi_A=m_A$.

I was thinking because every non zero vector of $\mathbb C^n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ so all eigenvalues need to be distinct and consequently  $\chi_A=m_A$

Am I right?

Comment: Why would all eigenvalues need to be distinct?

Comment: @5xum because different Eigen value will imply linearly independent Eigen vectors  and hence every vector of $\ C^n$ is eigenvector of $A$

Comment: Your logic is a bit off. Different eigenvalues imply different eigenvectors, sure, but they also imply that *linear combinations* of those eigenvectors **will not be eigenvectors**. For example, $$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ has different eigenvalues, different eigenvectors. But not every vector is eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: hmmm ok means  $$\begin{matrix}2 \\ 3\end{matrix}$$ is not eigenvector but linear combination of eigenvectors

Comment: What are you asking? Whether the statements are true or false?

Comment: @EricS. I am asking ''which of the following are true?''.

Answer (score 2):

$1.$ and $3.$ are true. If $v$ and $w$ are two non-zero eigenvectors with respect to different eigenvalues, then $v+w$ is not an eigenvector.

This shows that the assumption, that any vector is an eigenvector, implies that there are no two different eigenvalues. In particular, for $\lambda$ being the only eigenvalue, we obtain $Av = \lambda v$ for any $v$, i.e. $A = \lambda I$.

Additional note:
This is a nice and elegant (no need to mess around with indices and matrix multiplication) proof for the fact, that the center of the matrix ring contains only matrices of the form $\lambda I$, since any matrix $A$ with a non-eigenvector can not be contained in the center: Take a non-eigenvector $v$ and consider a basis $v,Av, \dotsc, $ and a basis $v,Av-v, \dotsc$. The matrix representation w.r.t these bases are obviously not the same (the first two entries of the first column are different), hence $A$ is not contained in the center, since its conjugation orbit has more than one element.